# I can not access element with jquery

Tags: jquery, find, parent

this is my code:

```
<div class="price-all mg-top-40px planolista">
                                   <span class="price1">3x<br>R$</span>
                                   <span class="price2">16,<span>63</span></span>
                                   <span class="avista">ou R$ 49,90 à vista</span>
                                   <select class="form-control form-plan variante" data-idplano="2">
                                                                 <option value="2">Light  3</option>
                                                                  <option value="3">Light  6</option>
                                                                  <option value="4">Light  9</option>                    
                                    </select>
```

and this is my js :

```
   $('body').on('change','.variante',function(){
   $.get("classes/acao.php", {mudarvalorplano: $(this).attr('data-idplano'), idvariavel: $(this).val()}, function(resposta){
      var retorno_reposta = resposta.split("###");

      $(this).parent('div').find('.price1').html('something');

   });
```

I can not change the content of the class price2

what should I do? Is there something wrong with this piece of code.

```
$(this).parent('div').find('.price1').html('something');
```

it is not working

=(

Comment: Why not just $(".price2").html("something") ?

Comment: `this` is refering to jqXHR object inside `$.get()` success callback, so use a closure

Comment: why these elements are repeated in the code, so I need to do this.

Comment: now it worked! I could not see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Only one `Price1` class is there in your code. For that why do you need a traversing.
Better use like this.

```
$('.price1').text('Something');
```

No need to use `.html` here I guess.

Comment: Thank you friends, it was the closure that was missing in the get method, now this ok!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it the jQuery way?

$(".price1").html("something");

Comment: I just change it by:

  $(this).parent("div").find(".price1").html("something");


and still does not work = (

Comment: Thank you friends, it was the closure that was missing in the get method, now this ok!

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure because inside `$.get()` success callback, `this` is referring to jqXHR object. See e.g:

```
$('body').on('change', '.variante', function () {
    var $price1 = $(this).closest('.price-all').find('.price1');
    $.get("classes/acao.php", {
        mudarvalorplano: $(this).data('idplano'),
        idvariavel: this.value
    }, function (resposta) {
        var retorno_reposta = resposta.split("###");    
        $price1.html('something');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace html() with text()